# Wordpress redirecting to home page for non existent page

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have following rule set in my htaccess. When I try to access any non existent page it redirects me to home page. How can I stop this redirection to home page. I need to show 404 page of my theme.

```
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: do you have a 404.pnp file

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled Permalinks? Also you need to check whether your Wordpress site uses .htaccess to do its redirections, have you tried changing the AllowOverride None directive to AllowOverride All ?

Comment: Permalinks are enabled, site is also using htaccess.